# is $[0,1]$ compact in topology generated by $\{(a, b): a<b\} \cup \{(a, b) \cap \mathbb{Q}: a<b\}$?

Tags: general-topology

I have to prove that, mi idea is create a coberture especific, and show that i can't take a finite collection, i was trying to see which can function, i was trying to check $[0, 1]$ in $k-$ topology to have an idea, but i did'not get it.

My teacher suggested me that i could take an open set with the form $(a, b)\cap \mathbb{Q}$ to cover rational numbers in $[0,1]$ and then take a sequence with rational numbers such that converges to $1$, and then create open intervals such that cover all the irrational numbers in $[0, 1]$, but i'm very stuck, i will really appreciate any clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** As in the suggestion, consider the covering $$[0,1]\subseteq \left((-1,2)\cap\mathbb Q\right)\cup\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(0,1-\frac{1}{n}\right).$$

Comment: thanks, just a question the covering contains $[0,1]$ really?

Comment: Yes, the interval should be closed; every rational in $[0,1]$ is contained in $(-1,2)\cap\mathbb Q$, while every irrational in $(0,1)$ is contained in some set of the form $\left(0,1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$.

Comment: Thanks thanks, i was a little bit confused, but im really greatfull.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to disprove compactness. Denote by $[0,1]_k$ the interval with the topology under scrutiny and by $[0,1]_u$ the interval with the usual topology.

Clearly the topology under scrutiny is finer than the usual topology, so the identity function $[0,1]_k\to[0,1]_u$ is continuous.

Suppose $[0,1]_k$ is compact. If a subset $A$ is closed, then it is compact. Then its image under a continuous function is compact. Since $[0,1]_u$ is Hausdorff, compactness implies closedness.

Now observe that the irrational numbers in $[0,1]_k$ are a closed set.

More generally, if $(X,\tau)$ is compact and Hausdorff, then $(X,\sigma)$ is not compact under any Hausdorff topology $\sigma$ such that $\sigma\subsetneq\tau$.

Comment: then it was by contradiction, we are going to asumme that [0, 1] is compact in $k-$ topology and for that reason [0,1] with the $u$ topolgy as u denote should be compact too, buy i don't get why $[0, 1]_{u}$ is hausdorff.

Comment: @FionaEverdeen I'm considering $[0,1]$ with the usual metric topology, which is Hausdorff (and compact).

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Bbb P = [0,1]\setminus \Bbb Q$, the irrationals in $[0,1]$.
If $[0,1]$ in this $k$-topology were compact, then $\Bbb P$ would also be, but  $\Bbb P$ has the same topology as subspace of the $k$-topology as it has in the standard topology on $[0,1]$ and $\Bbb P$ is dense in $[0,1]$ (usual ) so certainly not compact. So $[0,1]$ is *not* compact in the $k$-topology.